# How to Select Subjects Name from table when we are using only Subject Id in table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

How to Select Subjects Name from table when we are using only Subject Id in table and we are using another table Subject Master.

```
Table StudentMaster
--------------------------
StudentId   int Unchecked
StudentName varchar(50) Checked
Subject1    int Checked
Subject2    int Checked
Subject3    int Checked

Sample Record
------------------------------------
ID  Name    Subject1   Subject2   Subject3
1   Mohan      1           2         4
2   Sohan      3           2         5
3   Neha       5           1         2


Table Subject
-----------------------
SubjectId   int Unchecked
SubjectName varchar(150)    Checked

Sample Record
-----------------
SubjectId        SubjectName
   1                Hindi
   2                English
   3                Physics
   4                Chemistry
   5                Maths
```

How to Get Which subject are choosen by Sohan, Mohan and Neha???

I want the result like

```
StudentId   StudentName   Subject1    Subject2    Subject3
    1       Mohan         Hindi       English     Chemistry
    2       Sohan         Physics     English     Maths
    3       Neha          Maths       Hindi       English
```

Comment: You’ve tagged this question for three different databases. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: @Rajkumar Patro, if my post had solved your problem kindly marked it as answer so the question can be closed. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SM.StudentId,
    SM.StudentName,
    S1.SubjectName AS "Subject1",
    S2.SubjectName AS "Subject2",
    S3.SubjectName AS "Subject3"
FROM StudentMaster SM
LEFT JOIN Subject S1
     S1.SubjectId = SM.Subject1
LEFT JOIN Subject S2
     S2.SubjectId = SM.Subject2
LEFT JOIN Subject S3
     S3.SubjectId = SM.Subject3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
S.StudentId, 
S.StudentName,
S1.SubjectName AS Subject1,
S2.SubjectName AS Subject2,
S3.SubjectName AS Subject3
FROM StudentMaster S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subject S1
S1.SubjectId = S.Subject1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subject S2
S2.SubjectId = S.Subject2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subject S3
S3.SubjectId = S.Subject3
ORDER BY S.StudentId
```